# Creating multiple sites on Wordpress using subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, multisite, subdirectory

My client currently has a website on Wordpress which runs through a subdirectory (www.myclientsite.com/subdirectorysite1/). This website displays rental properties. They have asked me to create an additional website with an additional subdirectory (www.myclientsite.com/subdirectorysite2/) for a second prperty, and also create a new webpage for www.myclientsite.com which acts as a portal for the two property sites.

I have never done this before on Wordpress, and I've been exploring the possibility of using Wordpress Multisite. Does anybody have any experience with this? Or advice on what would be the best way to lay out these sites for both future page development, and daily management?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using creating a new folder 'subdirectorysite2' and then go for a fresh Wordpress installation.

If you have limited database creation access on the server, in that case, you can create a new template file on your existing WordPress theme and assign the new template to a page. After that change, the link of the page to subdirectorysite2. So that you can generate your desired URL i.e. www.myclientsite.com/subdirectorysite2/

And remember to modify .htaccess file as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wordpress multisite feature. https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network